# Do Lombok Builders use Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, lombok

Do Lombok Builders use Reflection?

or does it also add the necessary code pre-compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's definitely no reflection at all as Lombok uses *sort of* code generation. It works on the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) level, i.e., it works with the parsed source, somewhere between the source code and the bytecode.

A part of Lombok is [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok), which shows you rather exactly what code was generated.

Answer (score 4):

[The official site](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) is pretty clear on how `@Builder` works:

> `@Builder` can be placed on a class, or on a constructor, or on a method. While the "on a class" and "on a constructor" mode are the most common use-case, `@Builder` is most easily explained with the "method" use-case.
>
> A method annotated with `@Builder` (from now on called the *target*) causes the following 7 things to be generated:
>
> - An inner static class named `FooBuilder`, with the same type arguments as the static method (called the *builder*).
> - **In the *builder*: One private non-static non-final field for each parameter of the *target*.**
> - In the *builder*: A package private no-args empty constructor.
> - In the *builder*: A 'setter'-like method for each parameter of the *target*: It has the same type as that parameter and the same name. It returns the *builder* itself, so that the setter calls can be chained, as in the above example.
> - **In the *builder*: A `build()` method which calls the method, passing in each field. It returns the same type that the *target* returns.**
> - In the *builder*: A sensible `toString()` implementation.
> - In the class containing the *target*: A `builder()` method, which creates a new instance of the *builder*.

So for example, it might look like this:

```
public static class FooBuilder {
    private String abc;
    private String def;

    FooBuilder() {}

    public FooBuilder abc(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
        return this;
    }

    public FooBuilder def(String def) {
        this.def = def;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo build() {
        return new Foo(abc, def);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FooBuilder{abc: " + abc + ", def: " + def + "}";
    }
}
```